# ChebyShev Inequality problem to find the standard deviations

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be the claim amounts for insureds in risk class A, with a mean of 40 and a standard deviation of $\sigma_X$. Let $Y$ be the claim amounts for insureds in risk class B, with a mean of 55 and a standard deviation of $\sigma_Y$.
>
> Based on Chebyshev’s inequality, the upper bounds of $\Pr(X\ge95)$ and $\Pr(Y\ge120)$ are $\frac{1}{30}$ and $\frac{1}{40}$ respectively.
>
> Find $\dfrac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}$.

I got to:

$P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)={1\over k^2}$ so I have $$P(|135-40|\geq k\sigma) = {1\over 30}$$ $$P(|175-55|\geq k\sigma) = {1\over40}$$ but I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: In the first one, $k^2=30$ and $k\sigma =95$.

Comment: Wait, how do we know that $k\sigma = 95$? I know that the square is 30 but I thought that wouldn't get me anywhere.

Comment: For one, Chebyshev is an *inequality* not an equality. Secondly, you're applying the inequality incorrectly: you should have $P(X\ge95)=P(X-40\ge55)\le P(|X-40|\ge55)\le\frac{\sigma_X^2}{55^2}$.

Comment: @Jason I just received this problem on an adapt exam, I have never seen Chebyshev before. Can you explain how this is the case?

Comment: If the actuarial practice exam is bringing up Chebyshev's inequality and you have never seen it before, I think it is better to put the adapt exam down and understand Chebyshev thoroughly first.

Comment: One thing is that you probably won't really need ChebyShev for the P exam, it's not on the syllabus I don't think.

Comment: @Heavenly96: I dont think the syllabus needs to list the inequality explicitly to ask a question on it. Questions on Chebyshev have appeared and surprised students in the past. A casual search through actuarial outpost's  posts can give the insight that it is rather an easy inequality to learn which if asked can give an easy point that might make the difference between a pass vs. fail.

Comment: I don't think Chebyshev is ever on any "syllabus", but it is an elementary result that any student of probability should know. I agree with @Just_to_Answer, read about Chebyshev's inequality and go through some other examples - this is a kind of weird one which maybe you can come back to later.